# Why is my with statement skipped after while loop?

Tags: python

With this code (I added some prints to test where the code stops) I get this:

***do you have your details stored here already? y/n***    y

***Please enter a username***    Test

***debug: username_exists is True***

***debug: I ran this command***

***do you have your details stored here already? y/n***

```
import hashlib
import time

while True:
    have_account = input("do you have your details stored here already? y/n    ")
    while have_account not in ("y", "n"):
        print("please type either y or n")
        have_account = input("y/n    ")
    if have_account == "y":
        username_exists = False
        while username_exists is False:
            username_login = input("Please enter a username    ")
            with open("users.txt", "r") as f:
                readfile = f.read()
                if username_login in readfile:
                    username_exists = True
                    print("debug: username_exists is " + str(username_exists))
                else:
                    username_exists = False
                    print("That user does not exist")
        print("debug: I ran this command")
        with open("users.txt", "r") as f:
            readfile = f.read()
            user_loc = readfile.index(username_login)
            user_len = len(username_login)
            f.seek(user_loc + user_len + 3)
            pass_hash = f.read(64)
            password_login_hashed = None
            pass_matches = None
            while pass_matches is False:
                password_login = input("Please enter your password    ")
                password_login_hashed = hashlib.sha256(password_login.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
                password_login = None
                if password_login_hashed == pass_hash:
                    pass_matches = True
                    print("Congrats! You logged in!")
                else:
                    pass_matches = False
                    quit_question = input("Incorrect password! Please try again or type \"quit\" to quit")
                    if quit_question == "quit":
                        quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're initializing `pass_matches` to `None` and then you're checking `pass_matches is False` which will always return `False` because here pass_matches will always be `None`

**modify the while statement with this line of code:**

`while pass_matches in (False, None)`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think to add the code in the when statement. I edited the post and added it.
Edit: After adding more test prints it seems that everything in the with statement except for the test prints gets ignored.

Comment: @Neoxr check this it will surely work

Answer (score 0):

Why not read the file once at the beginning of the first loop?
like:

```py
import hashlib
import time

while True:
    with open("users.txt", "r") as f:
        readfile = f.read()
    have_account = input("do you have your details stored here already? y/n    ")
    while have_account not in ("y", "n"):
        print("please type either y or n")
        have_account = input("y/n    ")
    if have_account == "y":
        username_exists = False
        while username_exists is False:
            username_login = input("Please enter a username    ")
            if username_login in readfile:
                username_exists = True
                print("debug: username_exists is " + str(username_exists))
            else:
                username_exists = False
                print("That user does not exist")
        print("debug: I ran this command")
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran below code and check hardcoded value Test- it is printing "Pram" after last with statement as well ,See below image code which I ran and worked for me [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOn6n.png)

Please let me know if you still have any doubts .